# Invalid reCAPTCHA request. Missing challenge value

Tags: mvcrecaptcha

I'm using reCaptcha in an MVC application.
In controller i have 
RecaptchacontrolMVC.CaptchaValidator attribute.

My CaptchaValid always return false with the error message
"Invalid reCAPTCHA request. Missing challenge value."

```
[RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult Login(Model model, bool captchaValid, string     
                captchaErrorMessage)
 {
   if(captchValid)//this is false
 }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure But Re-captcha require 4 fields to verify as stated here.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

I believe you are missing the parameter "challenge" in your post request. Try to see whats getting passed in HTTPFox or Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the correct public key/private key combination for the URL that you set up for this Recaptcha control.